# How do I store a fingerprint(blob) in SQLCE 3.5?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I have a compact framework device that has a fingerprint scanner.  It's used to store Fingerprints as BLOBs in SQLite.  Due to various reasons I need to move the data to SQLCE.  What data type would I use?  varbinary or image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image, as the max size for varbinary with sql ce is 8000 bytes, image max is 1 GB